# Why am I getting "operation not permitted" when trying to install a Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm having some trouble when trying to run a very simple piece of code and couldn't find out what the reason could be.

I am getting

> operation not permitted

when trying to install a Linux kernel module from a `.ko` file (KO_NAME).

This is an excerpt of the code:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-init")==0) {

    fd=open(KO_NAME, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC);
    if (fd<0) {
      perror("Error");
      printf("Error number: %d\n", errno);
    } else {
      printf("fd: %d\n", fd);
    }
    uid=getuid();
    if (uid!=ROOT_UID) {
      printf("Error: not root\n");
      return -1;
    }
    if (access(KO_NAME, F_OK)==-1) {
      printf("Error: File \"%s\" doesn't exist\n", argv[2]);
      return -1;
    }
    rc=syscall(__NR_finit_module, fd, "", 0);
      close(fd);
      if (rc!=0) {
          perror("Error");
          printf("rc=%d\n", rc);
          printf("Error number: %d\n", errno);
      }
```

and this is the result when run:

```
fd: 3

rc=-1

Error number: 1
```

Why am I getting Error `number 1`?

> operation not permitted

Comment: Have you tried `/sbin/insmod <KO_NAME>`? It could be that modue file is not suitable for your kernel.

Comment: FYI: There is `finit_module()` wrapper for that syscall, see [man init_module](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html).

Answer (score 2):

I had "Operation not permitted" errors installing Linux kernels too. I am running Sophos Anti-Virus, which has a known bug. ["30s delay of file create and "Operation not permitted" errors with fanotify and cifs – This is a kernel issue and Sophos is working with the Linux community to fix this issue"](https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/118216)

To get around this problem I disable sophos-av before and enable it after each Linux kernel install. I have only experienced this problem during Linux kernel install and not during common updates.

`sudo /opt/sophos-av/bin/savdctl disable`

Run Update Manager and install Linux kernel.

`sudo /opt/sophos-av/bin/savdctl enable`

Comment: Same issue here with a recent kernel update in Ubuntu 20.04 :-(

Answer (score 0):

Kernel modules can only be accessed by the root user by default. 
So after `insmod` you have to open the device file with the root user.

So you have to use `sudo` for opening the file.